# Determinants Proof Can't Solve

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $v_1,\cdots ,v_n$ be vectors in $\mathbb R^n$.

Define $w_i$ as the vector in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, which is just $v_i$ with a $0$ added to the beginning. (So if $v_i = (1,0,1)$, then $w_i = (0,1,0,1)$.

How do I prove the following, using linearity and alternating properties of determinants?

$$\det(v_1\  \cdots\ v_n) = \det(e_1\ w_1\ \cdots\ w_n)$$
where $e_1 = (1,0,..,0)$.

I'm having a lot of trouble solving this. I can intuitively get why it would be true, based on computational formulas for matrices, but I can't see how to prove it.

Comment: Do you have to do it that way? It is trivial to do it by definition of determinant.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I am not allowed to use the definition of det...I think I am supposed to use this as a stepping stone to prove the det formula, with cofactors.

Comment: The proof is just an unraveling of the alternating properties. Write $v_i=\sum c_i b_i$ where $b_i$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then note $w_i=\sum c_ie_{i+1}$ where $e_i$ is the basis vector of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ that corresponds to $b_i$. Then use linearity and alternating properties to unravel all these coefficients.